# Finding Loop Invariant Proof, Help Please?

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics, loop-invariant

So I have this [assignment](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/course/1019/1019a4.pdf):

I need help with question 2.

I thought I knew how to do it, when I realized the factorials are being computed backwards. The algorithm is correct intuitively, but I can't seem to find a loop invariant that holds true before the loop starts.

I'm confused. Thanks.

Comment: So, you need help with the `2. You must do this assignment individually.` part?

Comment: Uuuh, the loop condition is actually there, I'm not sure what you're looking for. ( while y > 1 ) - This holds before the algorithm starts given you want to compute factorial of a legal number. (Aka. positive integer.)

Comment: Thanks sehe, I realize that...I tried really hard on my own, but can't figure it out :( And Scarlet, I know the loop condition is there, I need a loop invariant to prove the correctness of the algorithm - as far as I understand the concept. Thank you!

Comment: In this case it really seems like it would be appropriate to ask a teaching assistant or lecturer for guidance, not getting strangers on the internet to do it.

Comment: @Gian Uh oh Gian, he tagged it as ' homework '.

Comment: Ok Gian. I don't want anyone to do it for me anyways, I just need someone to point me in the right direction. I just don't get how I could set up an invariant that will be true before the loop executes and during the first iteration. Unless loop invariant statements can have conditional statements in them...very confused :(

Comment: @user1081456 Are we talking about the same loop invariants :) ? As far as i'm concerned, a loop invariant is for example while ( <loop invariant here> ). An expression that holds true before and during the execution of a loop. ('expected' (well, not always expected but you get the point) number of iterations)

Comment: Yep, that's what I mean. That's precisely the problem for me though. I can't find a loop invariant to prove that the factorial computation gives the correct result. Finding one for y to prove that the program terminates is trivial as you correctly stated above. But since I am new to this concept, I may not fully understand it either. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.  It does not change the result of the algorithm if you add `z <- y` before the loop begins.  Does that make your loop invariant easier to find?

Comment: YESS! I think it does!! I had thought of that, but I am just unsure if we are allowed to add statements just like that. Hmm...glad to see that I was on the right track at some point in my thought process. Thanks for the suggestion, I think I will go with it as it seems to be the only viable solution at this point.

Comment: Well if you're going to be formal about it you have to *prove* that it does not change your algorithm.  But that's not a hard proof. :D

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://homepages.ius.edu/rwisman/C455/html/notes/Chapter2/LoopInvariantProof.htm) is probably what you're looking for. It doesn't contain only the answer itself but also provides a useful explanation so i reckon it's good learning material.

Comment: Thanks! I did have this version figured out. See, the problem is that with my algorithm, the factorial is computed backwards. I may be overlooking some stupidly obvious fact though. I'll think about it more, but thank you :)